# Why am I getting 0's for output? Is it related to the formatting or the formula?

Tags: c, floating-point

1. Here is the issue, I am trying to convert from radians to degrees and pop out a number in degrees for theta2. However for radians theta2(rtheta2) and theta2 itself, keep returning as 0's. The formula is correct i think, so perhaps a format error?
2. Here is my code:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <math.h>

   #define PI 3.14159

   int main(void)
   {
       char input;
       int n1;
       float rn1;
       int n2;
       float rn2;
       int theta1;
       float rtheta1;
       float rtheta2;
       float theta2;

       printf("      Program Snell's Law:\n");
       printf("--------------------------------");
       printf("\n\nA> Enter indices of refraction of first angle.");
       printf("\nB> Calculate second angle of incdience.\n");

       scanf("%c", &input);
       printf("A> Enter indices of refraction of first angle.\n");
       scanf("%d", &n1);

       printf("Enter the index of material 2:\n");
       scanf("%d", &n2);

       printf("Enter the angle of incidence in region 1:\n");
       scanf("%d", &theta1);

       rn1=(M_PI /180) * n1;
       rn2=(M_PI /180) * n2;
       rtheta1=(M_PI /180) * theta1;

       theta2=asin((n1/n2) * sin(rtheta1));

       //need to convert back into degrees for radians theta 2~
       theta2=rtheta2*(180/M_PI);

       printf("%lf", rn1);
       printf("\n%lf", rn2);
       printf("\n%lf", rtheta1);

       printf("\n%lf", theta2);
       printf("\n%lf", rtheta2);
   ```

Comment: Do you by chance mean `rtheta2= asin((n1/n2) * sin(rtheta1));` instead of theta2?

Comment: And remove all of these blank lines...

Comment: either way, if i swap them out with each other, i still get 0 for both rtheta2 and theta2. And what do you mean blank lines? I figured it easier to read. Is that not the case?

Comment: i kept swapping the inputs in an attempt to just get a number out, and had no luck
Also, I am using Codeblocks IDE if that answers anything

Comment: indentation/formatting...............

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) then **use the debugger** `gdb` (so spend a few hours reading on how to use it)

Comment: Blank lines can improve readability of code, but you never need more than one blank line in a row.  For Stack Overflow in particular, adding so many blank lines means that we have to scroll to see all the code, which is not good for readability.

Comment: I will do so, thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Use floating-point math rather than integer division.

Integer division results in an integer quotient, yet code needs a FP result.

```
int n1, n2;
...
//                 v--- integer division.
// theta2= asin((n1/n2) * sin(rtheta1));
theta2 = asin((1.0*n1/n2) * sin(rtheta1));

// or re-order to effect FP divsiosn
theta2 = asin(sin(rtheta1)*n1/n2);
```

---

Watch out for using `asin()` outside the range `[-1.0...+1.0]` which may occur with computational results near +/- 1.0

```
double y = (1.0*n1/n2) * sin(rtheta1);
if (y > 1.0) y = 1.0;
else if (y < -1.0) y = -1.0;
theta2 = asin(y);
```